RecyclerView crash: Cannot call this method while RecyclerView is computing a layout or scrolling
I tried recyclerview.post{} and if(recyclerView.isComputingLayout)。but useless。
the bug repear when I add catch in my RecyclerView like this：
override fun onLayout(changed: Boolean, l: Int, t: Int, r: Int, b: Int) {
       try {
           super.onLayout(changed, l, t, r, b)
       } catch (e: IllegalArgumentException) {
           Ln.e(e)
       }
   }

if I remove the catch block，it will report an other bug: Scrapped or attached views may not be recycled. isScrap:false isAttached:true。
who can help me
